# Create matrix from data list in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list in MS Excel that looks like as follows:

```
735 1081 1377 2899 1318 723 1105 826 1126 792 761 1674
```

Now I want to make a matrix as follows:

- First 6 values for the first row
- from 2nd value to 7th for the second row
- 3rd to 8th for the 3rd row,..........
- last 6 values for the 6th row.

```
735  1081 1377 2899 1318 723

1081 1377 2899 1318 723  1105

1377 2899 1318 723  1105 826

2899 1318 723  1105 826  1126

1318 723  1105 826  1126 792

723  1105 826  1126 792  761
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bZf6.png):
[image]

Is there an easy way to create such a matrix? The only possible solution I have right now is to create the matrix manually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Excel provides the ability to do this by default.

However, it is possible to convert a single row of values into multiple rows using Kutools. It's a paid program but there's a 30 day free trial, so it'll solve your present requirement:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3276-excel-split-single-row-to-multiple-rows.html#kutools2